# Uncountable infinite family of uncountable subsets of an uncountable set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

Find an uncountable family of pairwise disjoint uncountable subsets, on an uncountable set B.

Comment: I found one. But I'm not going to give it to you.

Comment: (Also, please bother and search the site. Where your previous question is probably a duplicate, this one I'm pretty sure is a duplicate of an old question. Show some respect to the people who help you for *free* on the site.)

Comment: Are you allowed to choose the uncountable set $B$, or are you supposed to show that this can be done for **every** uncountable set $B$?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have great difficulty even finding my own answers with the search tool.  I don't feel like complaining when others can't find the duplicate questions.

Comment: @Ross: I have fairly good luck finding my own answers if I can remember a couple of useful words from them, but I use Google to do it, searching on `keyword keyword brian site:math.stackexchange.com`.

Comment: @Ross: Even if I'm wrong, and even if it wasn't asked before. I do expect that part of the process of asking a question is to try and figure out if the question was asked before. If the OP doesn't post any thought on the problem, and no thoughts about their effort to find out whether or not the problem was asked before, I will usually use my bad memory and decide whether or not this was asked or not. If the OP points out that they have searched the site, but didn't find; and they tried this or that, then that's a whole other thing.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm sorry if I offended you. I don't mean to disrespect at all. Please excuse me. I will try to search even better next time around. (Maybe its my way of typing when I search that gives me nothing.)

Comment: @Brian It was a bit confusing to me, but now when I think about it deeper, I think it is for any B we choose. Thanks for the hint too!

Comment: @Ross Thanks for the support. As I said, I don't mean to disrespect you amazing people who support us learners so well.

Comment: @user110842: You’re welcome! If you’re allowed to choose the $B$, you can simply ... oops! Never mind: Ross just posted the example that I was about to suggest.

Comment: No problem, and it's not a big deal. But before posting questions try and look around a little bit. See how good questions look like. Note that they all include your own efforts to solve the problem, and more than just the statement of the problem.

Comment: @Asaf I will do that from now on and include my own material too. Thanks for the hints!

Answer (score 1):

HINT: If $A$ is any infinite set, then $|A\times A|=|A|$ (assuming the axiom of choice).

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  If you get to choose $B$, a nice one is the infinite sequences of $0$'s and $1$'s.  If you think about alternate positions, you can find an explicit construction.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Since $A$ is uncountable $\aleph_1\leq|A|$. It suffices to show that you can split $\omega_1$ (or any set of size $\aleph_1$) into $\aleph_1$ parts. (This shows that the result in fact follows from a far weaker assumption than the axiom of choice.)